# Calling external JS from asp.net OnClientClick="return AddMore();"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

When i have my js code inline it works, but when i put it in an external js file with a link, it does not. Any ideas? the js link is in the head.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/ianeditworkhistory.js"></script>

function AddMore() {
    if (!ValidatePage())
        return false;

    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: why is the jquery linked directly and the second with a ../?  When you use your developer tools (f12), do you see any network errors?

Comment: I dragged the link for the second one, and psted the first one. The code displays the first record, then when you click more, it fails, but when the code is inline is works fine.
Thanks

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/ianeditworkhistory.js"></script> I dragged them both but still have the same issue. Thx